# Calender.HOUR_OF_DAY returns wrong results

Tags: java, calendar

I have written a code to get value of hour from a calender object , but it returns wrong result.

```
mpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

    try {
        time = sf.parse("09:00");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(time);

    System.out.println(cal);
    System.out.println(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

In First statement calender's toString method shows value 9 for Hour_OF_DAY , but cal.HOUR_OF_DAY prints 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) is a constant (with the value `11`) meant to be used together with the [`Calendar#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get-int-) method to retrieve the hour value:

```
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

This prints

```
9
```